# Increase Mouse Scroll Sensitivity in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scroll

How can I increase the vertical scrolling speed in eclipse?
Currently it's scrolling at one line per scroll tick.
I tried to search "mouse" in Windows -> Preferences but no results were found.
In my Control Panel -> Mouse -> Wheel -> Vertical Scrolling, number of lines at a time is set to "3".
I'm using Eclipse Kepler build 20130614-0229.
Appreciate for any helps.

Comment: For posterity: This randomly starts happening to me after a few minutes in an editor. Closing and reopening the editor fixes the scroll speed for a while. Eclipse 4.19.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently, Eclipse does not provide functionality to choose custom mouse scroll sensitivity in editors and views.

Nevertheless, you can push **CTRL key during the mouse scrolling** in editors to scroll an entire screen at a time.

Comment: This shorcut is really useful. Unlike Page Up/Down it doesn't move the cursor so it doesn't desellect the chosen item.

Comment: that does not work on Javadoc.. it increases the font sizes. does not work on Members, Outline, Package Explorer. Seriously this sucks.

Comment: interesting but I want to scrool 1 or 2 lines not 100. currently it steps by 0.5 line which is really unusable :-(.

Comment: My mouse scrolling is too fast in Eclipse IDE. I tried in windows settings but it just have slowed for non-coding part like browing, chrome etc etc and Eclipse IDE scrolling was as it was. I want to slow it for Eclipse IDE ? you have any way to slow ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Wizmouse software to increase number-of-lines per wheel tick

http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/

Comment: it is useless, because it is not application specific. same effect as standard mose driver that will increase it for all aplications.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Page up and page down on Windows PC to scroll 15-20 lines in a click.

Comment: Page up and page down scroll an entire screen. If your screen has 50 lines it scrolls 50 lines.